# Partial Stack trace while logging client exception

Tags: .net, exception

I have the following issue: 
We have an application already in production, and each exception the client gets is filtered through a method that gets the exception and presents its properties (including stack trace) via a message box:

```
private void HandleException(Exception ex)
```

Usually, this supplies enough information to realize where the exception happened in my application (which dll, which method and which line).
For example:

[image]
From this I can know that the exception occures in my EntitySearchControl class, at line 742, and I can fix the exception accordingly (Add a check for null in this case).

**The problem** is that sometimes I get a partial stack trace from the exception instance I got, for example:

**Message**: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index
**Source**: PresentationCore

**Stack Trace:**
[image]

And this is the entire stack trace I get. Now, we have like 10+ solutions in our project, and I can't know where is the source of this exception **in my application?**
All the stack trace is from .Net dll's, and I have no idea how to reproduce the problem and understand where it happened (in order to fix it).
I want to get more info to log into this message box that presents the exception's properties, so I could realize how to handle such unclear exceptions.

Maybe I should add another parameter for my private void HandleException(Exception ex) method, cause the exception instance which includes the stack trace property does not seem to be enough for these cases.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In WPF (and other XAML driven UI's) this usually occurs when parts of the visual tree are updated / changed from a background thread, instead of the UI thread. See if you can find instances where that might be the case.

Comment: @Willem van Rumpt , Can you please elaborate more?
The exception above, I actually can reproduce, it happened while building the WPF TreeView dynamically, and it probably didn't happen via the UI thread.

Comment: I'm afraid there's little to elaborate. Updating of (parts of) the visual tree in WPF *must* be done on the UI thread. Attempts to do so from a different thread (for instance while executing a BackgroundWorker) always results in failure and a crash. And one of the aspects of those crashes is that it won't leave behind a complete stack trace. Move the offending code out of the non UI thread, or synchronize it with the UI thread (for instance by using the Dispatcher https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx).